# Level shifting at the output of a 2:1 multiplexer

Tags: arduino, usb, uart, bluetooth, multiplexer

In my design a custom implementation of an Arduino Uno talks to either a CP2104 USB-UART or a bluetooth module, through a multiplexer (74LVC1G3157). Priority is given to the wired connection and hence when the USB cable is plugged in (sensed with the VBUS of the USB), power to the BT module is turned off and hence is inactive.

The CP2104 and the Bluetooth have 3.3V outputs and the Arduino Uno is a 5V device. For the Arduino RX, a 3.3V from either the CP2104 or the BT module works without any conversion and for the TX there is a voltage divider that steps down to 3.3V level to be read into the BT module and the CP2104 has 5V tolerant lines and hence there is no conversion there. However, the DTR line that resets the Arduino should be 5V and I was wondering if the way its wired in the schematic would work ok? (74LVC1G3157 followed by the 74LVC1G17). The 74LVC1G17 is simply a buffer.

Comment: why not run the arduino at 3.3V as well?

Comment: Can't because the Arduino runs motor control chips that require 5V levels.